# SurfaceView on ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-constraintlayout

I have a trouble with surfaceView (camera app) when put it on ConstraintLayout and use Guidelines with percents.
The stupid thing is that appears only on samsung S7 edge phone (Nougat) (I have two one - chinese (Kitkat) and samsung, and chinese works correctly)

The layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/cameraView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomGuideline"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topGuideline" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scanButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Scan"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/topGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/bottomGuideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />
```

I figured out that problem is that I use 0dp (or wrap_content) for layout_width and layout_height in my surfaceView (because of that surfaceCreated() callback in surfaceView.holder.addCallback() isn't invoked). So when I use say 30dp or match_parent it works. But I must use 0dp to fit Guidelines!

Does anybody know how to fix this keep using constraintLayout?
Thanks.